# Format Windows Form Text Box Display

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datatable, newline

I am using a `BindingNavigator`and binding my `BindingSource` which is a DataTable to a textbox. I am populating the DataTable like this `newRow["Email"] = listItem["User_Email_Primary_23x"];` then I am binding the DataTable row to my text box like this `txtEmail.DataBinding.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "Email");`

Now the issue that I have is that data in the DataTable appears like the below ->

```
XXXXXXX@XXXX.com; XXXXXX@XXXX.com; XXXXXXXXXX@XXX.com;
```

So when the data displays in the text box on the winform it all displays side by side seperated with a semi-colon. What I want to do is update the visual display so that when the email addresses from the DataTable are displayed in the text box each email is displayed on top of each other and have the text box "Auto Expand" so all of the emails are shown. So my desired display results would be

```
XXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.com;
XXXXXXXX@XXX.com;
XXXXXXXX@XXX.com;
```

How would I format the `txtEmail.DataBinding.Add...` line to display in my desired format?

EDIT - Additional Info -
Thanks to comments provided by @Fabio - I have gotten the below syntax but I am getting 2 compile errors.

```
private void AddLineBreak(object sender, ConvertEventArgs cevent)
{
    string dtValue = cevent;
    var result = dtValue.Contains(";") ? string.Join("<br>", dtValue.Split(';')) : cevent;
}

public void BindData()
{
    Binding b = new Binding("Text", bindingSource1, "Email");
    b.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(AddLineBreak);
    txtEmail.DataBinding.Add(b);
}
```

Which now presents me with 2 compile errors:

```
cevent in the line `string dtValue = cevent;` is underlined providing error of
```

> Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ConvertEventArgs' to string

And the second error I get is on the line

```
dtValue.Contains(";") ? string.Join("<br>", dtValue.Split(';')) : cevent;
```

providing an error of

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.Windows.Forms.ConvertEventArgs'

What should I do differently to avoid these compile errors?

Comment: For formatting you can defined a handler for `Binding.Format` event.

Comment: @Fabio -> I have seen examples on how to add a handler for `Binding.Format` to format as currency or format decimal places etc, but I am still in the dark on how to add a NewLine everytime a semi-colon is encountered.

Comment: Try to use `string.Split` and `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @Fabio - you my friend have taken me one step closer, but I am getting 2 compile errors.  Will you view my edit and try to assist please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter `ConvertEventArgs cevent` is object which contain information about formatted value. Purpose of eventhandler to update `cevent.Value` property to desired value.

In Format eventhandlers is good practice to check for type your are going to convert to. In your case you will check that `.DesiredType` property equal `String` type.

Since `cevent.Value` is of type `object` you need to cast it to original type before executing any operations

```
private void AddLineBreak(object sender, ConvertEventArgs cevent)
{
   if (cevent.DesiredType != typeof(string)) return;

   var originalValue = cevent.Value.ToString();   
   cevent.Value = originalValue.Replace(";", Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I think `Replace` will serve your needs as well and seems it will be more comprehensible.

Comment: This will throw an error if the field is null.  should I encompass in a try/catch and ignore the error?

Comment: I tried to handle it with `if (cevent.DesiredType != typeof(System.DBNull)) { //do the above from your example }`

Comment: @HotTomales, you can use `cevent.Value.ToString()` for converting original value to string. `DbNull.ToString()` will always return empty string.

Comment: _should I encompass in a try/catch and ignore the error?_ - don't. Use `try..catch` only when you want/need to handle possible exception. Usually if you expecting exception to happen - it is not exception anymore and should be handled as part of logic. Good examples for using `try ... catch` is connection errors or continuous execution, where you want execution to continue even exceptions raised